# How can I approximately calculate the Solr index size

Tags: solr

How can I approximately calculate the index size (memory usage) created with solr? I know there are a lot of variables that enter into the computation, but simply about whether it takes 10GB or 10MB.

For example I have 1000 documents,fields only *id* and *text* and want to decide if the field type will be string or text_general. How the size change if I add another field.

Maybe, if anybode could be so grateful and write here some statistics about real indexes.

Comment: Index size is not the same as memory usage. Index size is how much disk space the Solr index occupies, whereas memory usage depends on a lot of different factors, based on your querying and indexing operations.

Comment: Deciding whether `text` is a string or a text_general field depends on your query requirement. `string` will need less space than any `text` type since it stores the value verbatim without any analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr index size would depend upon a number of factors

1. The number of fields defined
2. The configuration of these fields, where indexed or stored. Stored fields will usually cause a index to grow
3. The type and the field types defined for the field. e.g. String fields are stored as a whole. However, text fields would have multiple tokens generated depending upon the type of analyses performed on the fields. e.g. edge gram, ngrams, synonyms etc would cause multiple tokens to be generated and if stored would be maintained in the index.
4. The content of the fields you are indexing. If the tokens generated are more common and not unique you would have a small index size as Lucene stored the tokens dictionary seperate and just have pointers to the tokens from the documents.
5. Maintaining position can very expensive for the Index size so avoid it if not using positions

and much much more.

Comment: Is there any tool which calculates per index size / total index size?